# Displaying a table over an image with CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I want to display these 3 grey buttons on the banner. Everything i tried didn't work.

[image: My current state]

[image: How it should look like]

This is the html code:

```html
    <nav>
         <img class="banner" src="img/Banner.png" alt="Banner">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <a href="index.html">Index</a>
               </td>
               <td class="separator">
                  
               <td>
                  <a class="active" href="seiteA.html">Seite A</a>
               </td>
               <td class="separator">
                  
               </td>
               <td>
                  <a href="seiteB.html">Seite B</a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
 </nav>
```

I am new to HTML and CSS so i appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices:

- It is not a good practice to use a `<table>` for navigation, you can use something like `<ol>`/`<ul>` as shown in [`nav`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) documentation on  MDN or even `<div>`s within `display:flex` container.
- You can use the image as the `background-image` of the `<nav>` so that you don't have to position the navigation elements on top of it yourself.

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/100");
}

ol {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Seite A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Seite B</a></li>
    <li>Seite B C</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

---

Quick answer to help you move forward with what you currently have: You can make your `nav` a relative positioned container and `absolute` position your table on top of it anywhere you want.

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img class="banner" src="img/Banner.png" alt="Banner">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="index.html">Index</a>
      </td>
      <td class="separator">

        <td>
          <a class="active" href="seiteA.html">Seite A</a>
        </td>
        <td class="separator">

        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="seiteB.html">Seite B</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</nav>
```